# Supplying current URL to "Path override" in Panels with Views pane

Tags: 7, panels, views

Sorry if this is a known bug but I searched and couldn't find a related issue.

I have a view which has a "Feed" display (xml), and a "Views Pane" display.

On the "Feed" display the supplied path/URL for the display is "feed/xml".

The "Views Pane" display has a contextual filter for "Taxonomy term" and also a pager that has "Expose the Items Per Page" set to on.

Now when the "Views Pane" is included in a Panel, the Contextual Filter value (term id) is supplied from the Panel context (Node being viewed: term field on node). So now when you view the panel page and try to change the Items Per Page exposed form, it tries to submit the form to the "Feed" display's path which is "feed/xml" and that's wrong. Ideally the `#action` of the exposed form should be submitting to the current URL.

So I went back to the view and edited the "Views Pane" display, opened to "Allowed settings" and set "Path override" to on. And then went to the Panel config, and I put `%node:url` as the "Path override".

All well and good so far, but now when I view the Panel page and look at the exposed form's `#action` its the correct url BUT with added extra parameter which is the Contextual Filter's taxonomy term id. For example: if my current page is `path/to/my/page` then the `#action` of the form is `path/to/my/page/115` where 115 is the ID of the taxonomy term currently supplied to the views pane through the panel context. So submitting the form produces a 404 in this case.

What I've tried so far is: 
- Preprocessing the panel pane (theme_preproces_panel_pane) which didn't help a great deal as the view was already rendered as HTML in the `content` key of the `$variables` array. At this point I realized preprocessing theme functions won't work.
- So I moved on to Views hooks and tried `hook_views_pre_render`. `dpm`-ing the `$view` from this hook, I can see that `$view->override_path` (string) is the correct URL (without the extra term id), but the exposed form was also already rendered here in `$view->exposed_widgets` (string, rendered HTML) with the wrong URL (with extra term id).

So before I go through all Views hooks, and maybe not even come up with a solution, I wanted to ask this question, if **anyone knows when exactly this exposed form is being rendered OR how I can stop the Taxonomy Term ID from being attached to `%node:url` token** (Perhaps a simple configuration that I've missed or.. ?).

**Edit**

So I went through all the Views hooks. Also implemented a `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter`. From the order the `dpm`'s are being outputted, it looks like the order of execution is:

- `hook_views_pre_build`
- Exposed form gets built (dpm of hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter)
- `hook_views_post_build`
- `hook_views_pre_execute`
- `hook_views_post_execute`

In `hook_views_pre_build` the `path_override` is correct. Form is not rendered yet.

In `hook_views_exposed_form_alter` the form render array is built, and `$form['#action']` shows the wrong path with the extra term id.

So I need to somehow get in between these 2 functions and supply the correct #action...

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer, I'm not 100% sure why the argument is added to the URL, though I know I've done the same thing at some point and worked it out. A simple way to workaround it might be to have the page take an optional argument in the form is the term id. Not sure about it though, so commenting instead of answering.

Comment: If you have the incorrect `#action` in the form alter, why don't you just correct it there?

Comment: Oh of course... KISS ... `view` is available in `$form_state['view']` ... didn't know that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer why exactly the term id is being attached (hoping someone might shed light on that), the simple solution thanks to @Letharion was to use the `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter`:

```
function hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $view = $form_state['view'];

  if($view->name == 'exhibitions' && $view->current_display == 'panel_pane_3') {
    $form['#action'] = $view->override_path;
  }
}
```